# MDX query - Subselect with multiple OR conditions inside AND condition

Tags: mdx

I have a requirement where I need to implement a subselect with multiple ORs inside an AND.

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Ele1].[Value].&[1000] 
    AND ([Ele2].[Value].&[20] OR [Ele3].[Value].&[200]) 
    AND [Ele4].[Value].&[15] 
    AND ([Ele5].[Value].&[10] OR [Ele6].[Value].&[100])} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [CubeName];
```

This is an algorithm of the kind of query I would like to implement. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which OLAP server are you using? FYI, in icCube you could use subcubes (http://www.iccube.com/iccube/shopping-cart-advanced-analytics-iccube-mongodb-ii-subcubes/, http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SubCubeUnion.php)

Comment: I am using SQL server analysis services.

Comment: Are these `Ele2, Ele1, ...` different attribute hierarchies within the same dimension or are they different dimensions?

Comment: It may be of different dimensions.

Comment: Is it not possible to create this kind of an MDX query to get data from the SSAS cube?